# Is a ViewController unloaded from memory after being dismissed?

Tags: ios, swift

I noticed that the state of variables doesn't preserve among different presentations of a View Controller.

```
    var starrySky = StarrySky() // this has a state property which is false initially
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if starrySky.state == false { starrySky.createSky(for: self.view) }
        if starrySky.state != false { starrySky.resumeSkyAnimations()} // this never runs

    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        starrySky.state = true // here im changing the state
        starrySky.removeSkyAnimations()
    }
```

So whenever I dismiss this ViewController and present it again my `starrySky.state` is always false. I have the same code in the same methods in my `rootViewController` and whenever I change views the state preserves.

- So does this mean that any VC's presented modally are dismissed from
  memory after you call `dismiss(animated:,completion:)`?

Comment: Are you creating the viewcontroller's object each time you present it? It would be great to see the viewcontroller creation and presentation code. And, yes, any dismissed VC is removed from the memory unless it has a reference somewhere, or is retained.

Comment: No, I'm simply presenting the VC via prepare for segue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So does this mean that any VC's presented modally are dismissed from memory after you call dismiss

Normally, yes. View controllers form a hierarchy or chain of parent/presenter and child/presented. The former owns and retains the latter, and releases it when the latter is removed. The root controller is never removed unless you deliberately replace it.

Comment: Oh ok, I thought that it gets unloaded only if the app gets backgrounded

Comment: No, backgrounding has no effect on the view controller hierarchy. If it did, the view controller would be missing when you are foregrounded again. If _that_ happens, you have much bigger problems.

Comment: Similarly `viewWillAppear/Disappear` is totally unrelated to backgrounding.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you present the view again the variable starrySky is initialized again with false 
you can save the state using userDefaults in viewWillDisappear and read it in viewWillAppear